# Extract number from a URL in Redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I would like to extract an ID (a number) from a bunch of URLs in Redshift. I know I can use `regexp_substr` for this purpose, but my knowledge of regular expressions is weak. Here are a couple example URLs:

```
/checkout?feature=ADVANCED_SEARCH&upgradeRedirect=%2Fmentions%3Ftop_ids%3D1222874068&btv=feature_ADVANCED_SEARCH
/checkout?feature=ADVANCED_SEARCH&trigger=mentioning-author-rw&upgradeRedirect=%2Fmentions%3Ftop_ids%3D160447990
```

After parsing the above URLs, I would like the output to be:

```
1222874068
160447990
```

Note that the parameter `top_ids` remains constant and will help break the URL.
I tried using multiple versions of `split_part` as well. But there may be variations in the URL where it might break. So using a regular expression may be a better idea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(yourcolumn, 'top_ids%3D([0-9]{2,})'), 11, 20)
```

Just looking for 'top_ids%3D' and 2 or more digits after it.
Then removes the first 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select regexp_substr(column,'top_ids%3D([0-9]*)', 1, 1, 'e')
```

The `'e'` extracts the substring in (brackets).